# Validation of invisible fields on submit

Tags: validation, symfony

(Symfony 2.8)

I want to insert data into a form as steps in a process.

The field to validate is in "Descripción" tab and the submit buttons are in the "Guardar/Revisión" tab.

When I click the submit button, it displays the error "An invalid form control with name='form[proDescripcion]' is not focusable" in the Chrome debug console.

Is it possible to correct the error without changing the design?

```
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Descripción</p>
      <div class="inputText">
        <div class="label">
            <label for='proDescripcion' >{{ form_label(form.proDescripcion) }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
          {{ form_widget(form.proDescripcion) }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Imagen/Documento</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Datos</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
      <p>Guardar/Revisión</p>
      {{ form_row(form.save) }}
      {{ form_row(form.finish) }}
    </div>
```

[image: Design of page]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "novalidate" attribute to your form

```
{{ form_start(contact, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

With this attribute, HTML5 will not try to validate your form on submit. Don't forget to do it on the server-side with assert annotation.

Comment: This way I lose all configured validations (asserts).
Is this the only solution?

Comment: you should not loose assert validation, this attribute just disable html5 form validation